# Windows not detecting my half of ram , but CPU-Z detected it

Tags: memory

Specs -
i3-4010u
4 ram slots
4gb(installed by company)
(previously instaleed memory was - 1660mzh , DDR3L,UNKNOW COMPANY)
(New brought memory was - 1333mzh ,DDR3 , Kingston)
laptop - Lenevo g50-70

I have 4 gb of installed memory in m[enter image description here][1]y laptop , I brought another 4gb of memory so it is not detected by my laptop but it is detected by cpu-z perfetcly.
And that 4gb ram is working on another laptop properly.
So what should i do now.

Comment: 32 or 64 bit version of Windows?  The former can't use the memory even if it sees it.

Comment: You might also check your BIOS to see if you got all the memory in.